# In python, issue a get request to a ipv6 link-local address

Tags: python, networking

Is there a standard way to issue an HTTP GET request to a url using any standard python library, with the major caveat that the host address is an ipv6 link-local address (heavy emphasis on "link-local")? The target machine that is running the server does not have any ip address other than the raw link-local ip address that includes the mac address (hence it can only be reached by an address that looks something like "fe80:::%eth0" where "%eth0" is the network interface on the client that shares a broadcast domain with the server).

Comment: Does it have to be the Python Standard Library? Is a 3rd-party library appropriate?

Comment: This configuration implies that the server is on the other end of a link directly connected to the host you want to run the HTTP GET request from.  Is that the case?  Can you describe the network configuration more completely?  Why doesn't the host's normal routing policy handle this for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Twisted's HTTP client API](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function

from sys import argv

from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP6ClientEndpoint
from twisted.web.client import ProxyAgent
from twisted.internet.task import react

def main(reactor, address, uri):
    server = TCP6ClientEndpoint(reactor, address, 80)
    agent = ProxyAgent(server, reactor)
    getting = agent.request(b"GET", uri)
    def got(response):
        print("Got {}".format(response.code))
    getting.addCallback(got)
    return getting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    react(main, argv[1:])
```

For example:

```
$ python http-proxy-get.py ::1 http://example.com/
Got 200
$
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, can you elaborate on the syntax? How is this command line invocation supplying three arguments to main? It looks like only two are being passed. Is `::1` a reference to localhost? If that's the case then why are two addresses being supplied (i.e., `::1` and `example.com`). I've messed around with the args but either get exceptions or "Got 400" errors.

Comment: `react` passes elements from its second argument to the function given as its first argument.  `::1` on the command line is passed for the `address` parameter.  `http://example.com/` on the command line is passed for the `uri` parameter.  These are given separately so that the HTTP client knows where to connect separately from knowing what URI to request (which seemed to be a component of your question).  On further reflection, I think maybe you were asking something different and this answer isn't entirely helpful.