# In python, use an open socket to send an http request

Tags: python, networking

This is a follow up to the previous question that may hopefully be easier to solve. Here's the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544051/in-python-issue-a-get-request-to-a-ipv6-link-local-address?noredirect=1#comment38010962_24544051). I'm having difficulty using `httplib` to send an http request to an ipv6 link-local address. However, I can create a socket connection successfully to an ipv6 link-local address by the following:

```
from socket import *
addrinfo = getaddrinfo('fe80::<rest>:<of>:<my>:<address>%eth0', <my-port>, AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM)
(family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) = addrinfo[0]
s = socket(family, socktype, proto)
s.connect(sockaddr)
```

Is there a way to use this socket to send http requests without resorting to manually implementing http? For example, by passing the open socket to an existing http client library (for python 2.x). Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. With `scapy` you can create http request as you like, then send packets through this socket and get response as well.
As for existing http client library which can accept an open socket, I have never heard of...